# how to write web services CRUD operations for perticular Drupal content types

Tags: services

I have Installed following modules;

1. [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services)
2. [Restful](https://www.drupal.org/project/restful)
3. [Services view](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views)

Enabled these modules and created one *services view* for one content type(content type name: employees).

Then opened *structure->services*, created an *endpoint* and enabled view service(employee).

Service accessing Url **Ex:**  http://localhost:82/test/employees

Now data is accessing well.

But how can I do web services *CRUD* operations for this content type?

Comment: I have a blog post that covers all the Services CRUD calls in detail: http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/drupal-services-examples

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein how can we wright custom CRUD operation code? i want that example.

Comment: You wouldn't need that unless you have a custom entity type, and even then you shouldn't because the services_entity module exists to facilitate this. Since you have a content type, you'll just use the Node CRUD resource. If you want to make a custom service, you can use the http POST method and this blog post: http://www.drupalgap.org/node/187

Comment: @tyler.frankenstein i have read your blog (http://tylerfrankenstein.com/user/4/code/drupal-services-examples) you are explaing very clearly about services.

Comment: i have a content type custom content type registration,so i want perform a CRUD operations to get the data and create the data through phonegap,how can i do CRUD operaations for registration nodes.

Comment: checkout jDrupal and/or DrupalGap to more easily create nodes in PhoneGap. Otherwise you just follow the Node Create example on the blog post linked above.